# Python: TransportableException: TransportableException

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyrcca

I am using a package from online called Pyrcca. I am running through this tutorial: https://github.com/gallantlab/pyrcca/blob/master/Pyrcca_usage_example.ipynb but using my own input code:

```
# Split into training and validation data
TCIA_train, TCIA_test = train_test_split(TCIA_reduced, test_size=0.2)
TCGA_train, TCGA_test = train_test_split(TCGA, test_size=0.2)

# Initialize a cca object as an instantiation of the CCACrossValidate class.
ccaCV = rcca.CCACrossValidate(kernelcca=False, numCCs = [5,10], regs = [0.8, 0.5, 0.1, 1e2])

# Use the train() and validate() methods to run the analysis and perform cross-dataset prediction.
ccaCV.train([TCIA_train, TCGA_train])
testcorrsCV = ccaCV.validate([TCIA_test, TCGA_test])
```

Based on this, I encounter an error that I have never seen before and that I am unable to debug. I am hoping for some help. Thanks!

It says

> "TransportableException: TransportableException"

Error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-c44a925b202d> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # Use the train() and validate() methods to run the analysis and perform cross-dataset prediction.
----> 5 ccaCV.train([TCIA_train, TCGA_train], False)
      6 testcorrsCV = ccaCV.validate([TCIA_test, TCGA_test])

~/PycharmProjects/thesis_code/Thesis_code/Packages/rcca.py in train(self, data, parallel)
    171                             kernelcca=self.kernelcca, ktype=self.ktype,
    172                             gausigma=self.gausigma, degree=self.degree,
--> 173                             cutoff=self.cutoff, selection=selection)
    174                         running_corr_mean_sum += fold_corr_mean
    175 

~/PycharmProjects/thesis_code/Thesis_code/Packages/rcca.py in train_cvfold(data, reg, numCC, kernelcca, ktype, gausigma, degree, cutoff, selection)
    202                 for ind in chunk]
    203     notheldinds = list(set(range(nT)) - set(heldinds))
--> 204     comps = kcca([d[notheldinds] for d in data], reg, numCC,
    205                  kernelcca=kernelcca, ktype=ktype,
    206                  gausigma=gausigma, degree=degree)

~/PycharmProjects/thesis_code/Thesis_code/Packages/rcca.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    202                 for ind in chunk]
    203     notheldinds = list(set(range(nT)) - set(heldinds))
--> 204     comps = kcca([d[notheldinds] for d in data], reg, numCC,
    205                  kernelcca=kernelcca, ktype=ktype,
    206                  gausigma=gausigma, degree=degree)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2131         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2132             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2133             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2134         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2135             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2175             return self._take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2176         else:
-> 2177             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2178             return self._take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2179 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1267                 if mask.any():
   1268                     raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'
-> 1269                                    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
   1270 
   1271                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: '[ 0  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 18 19 20 22 23 24 25 26 27\n 28 30 34 35 36 37 39 40 41 42 43 44] not in index'
```

I am wondering whether the "\n" is a problem?

Comment: I have updated the error log with the latest one.

Comment: `pyrcca` doesn't look like a widespread and well-known library yet, so you might have more luck [filing an issue](https://github.com/gallantlab/pyrcca/issues/new) on GitHub than asking here. In either case, please provide a [mcve] and find out whether this is specific to your custom input code or also happens when following the tutorial closely. If the former, try to find the minimal deviation from the tutorial that still triggers the error.